# Base 64 encode and decode on Android

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, base64

Converting MP4 video to Base64 and then send it to client to play the video. It works great on all browsers **but NOT in Android.**

**PHP encode mp4 video**

```
$filename = get_template_directory().'/video/'.$video_id.'.mp4';
$array[$video_id] = 'data:video/mp4;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
//$array[$video_id] = '/wp-content/themes/nat5/app2/video/'.$video_id.'.mp4';
```

**JS Load & play video**

```
$('.js-session-video').attr('src', base64_string );
document.getElementById('video_run').load();
document.getElementById('video_run').play();
```

**Errors**

I am not getting any errors on Android devices it just frise and I need to restart chrome app

**Test with video url**

Video url instead of base64 string and it works

Comment: Try making a test page that plays the video on android unecoded to see if Android can play that video at all.

Comment: I did test to use the video URL instead of base64 string and all works. I did change in PHP section (about with // line).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you base64-encode the video to begin with? Remember that base64 encoded data is bigger than the original, so I wouldn't do it for mobile (where bytes really matters).

Comment: True. It they only way I know to make a set of video available offline.